# Issue while using Vert.x and PowerMockito in Junit

Tags: java, junit, vert.x, powermockito

I am  writing JUnit tests for a Vert.x application. I need to use Powermock and Vert.x runner classes for my JUnit test. I am trying to use below code to integrate both runners:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(VertxUnitRunner.class)
```

Still when I try to create a Vertx object by:

```
vertx = Vertx.vertx();
```

I get the below error and no Vert.x object is returned:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to transform class with name
>   io.vertx.core.net.impl.transport.KQueueTransport. Reason: cannot find
>   io.netty.channel.kqueue.KQueueEventLoopGroup

I am using `javaassist.3.21.0-GA.jar`

Anyone has faced similar issues?